# How to Extract Arabic/Farsi(rtl) Text from docx file in a right order

Tags: python, text, right-to-left

I am trying to extract huge amount of text from some docx files and store them in .txt files.

the language I am working with is farsi/arabic (they are right to left languages) , so i have difficult time using python-docx. I can't extract texts in appropriate form, they all be mixed up in .txt file.

extracted form = https://pasteboard.co/Id8jj7g.jpg

original form = https://pasteboard.co/Id8jv1i.jpg

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document('1.docx')
text_file = open('data.txt','w', encoding='utf8')


print(len(doc.paragraphs))

for txt in doc.paragraphs:
    text_file.write(txt.text+'\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

I think first the appropriate form need to be defined. if you are working on a NLP project you need to have the sentences and each word in the sentences. I think the following code can be helpful for extracting text from a docx file. (Python 2.7)

```
# library (using pip for installing the libraries)
import docxpy
import codecs

# read Input file : Input.docx
file = 'Input.docx'

# extract text from file 
text = docxpy.process(file)

# save the extracted text to a text file 
output_txt = codecs.open('Input.txt','w','utf-8')
output_txt.write(text)
output_txt.close()
```

read the docxpy documentation for more information: 
[docxpy website](https://pypi.org/project/docxpy/)